# How to Check If 100% Covered WebElement is Clickable with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have two divs with absolute position

```
<div id="4711" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;background-color:red">Visible later</div>
<div id="4712" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;background-color:green">To be removed</div>
```

and some Javascript (not shown here) that removes 4712 after a while (lets say after 2 seconds) from the DOM.

Now, in my Selenium tests I want to check if 4711 is clickable. 
From a user's perspective it is only clickable after 4712 has been removed.

So I tried

```
new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("4711")));
```

However, 4711 is always clickable (enabled=true, displayed=true), even before 4712 is removed.

Is there any way how to check if 4711 is realy clickable, that is, clickable from a user's perspective (ideally without using Javascript)?

Comment: That's pretty interesting question, a few hours ago I have had a long argument with @Andersson that it's really not checking whether element is clickable. The truth is, Selenium doesn't have the way to check whether element is clickable or not. There are some other way through JavaScript but it is actually difficult one.

Comment: You can let your script know or after invisibility of web element with id `4712`, 

    new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibiltyOf(By.id("//div[contains(text(),'To be removed')]")));

Then you can check for element with id **4711** whether it is clickable. However , it is clickable every time as you have mentioned.

Comment: @cruisepandey That's a workaround actually. Selenium really doesn't have the way to check whether element is clickable or not.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Can you be bit specific , I mean how did you come to that conclusion ?

Comment: @cruisepandey because they are checking whether element is enabled or not in the method elementtobeclickable, that wouldn't let you know whether element is clickable or not. So selenium has no way to know! This was a bigger discussion in WATIR because WATIR plans to include the method to check whether element is clickable or not.

Comment: What makes 4711 clickable only afer 4712 is gone? Is it disabled or ? Can you share a link to the page? My guess is some CSS gets applied to it that would indicate that it's available to click (to the user) and you could look for that but we're guessing that this point without more info.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : If the element is visible and enabled then we can assume that it is clickable. That's what we have internally in elementToBeClickable method

Comment: @cruisepandey If that's the case, then you should not be met with `ElementClickInterceptedError` error while you write `elementToBeClickable` method because it has to wait until the element which overlay your element disappears, but it doesn't. So it's not the case as you imagine. So it's not checking whether element is clickable or not really. It's simply checking whether element is enable or not.

Comment: @Rajagopalan :That's why I have mentioned we assume , if it is visible and enabled.

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes it's an assumption My point is, `elementToBeClickable` is clearly not doing it's intended Job. When you wait for an element visibility, it has to wait for it to become visible, when you wait for an element to become clickable, it needs to wait for element to become clickable, but it would not, so the function is clearly not doing the JOB what it is written for! As you say it's just an assumption, but this function can be used if element is changing from disabled state to enable state then waiting for to be enabled  not for waiting to be clickable to be exact.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Well , your statements might be true. I am heavy user of `elementToBeClickable` BTW :)

Comment: @cruisepandey You can obviously use it when you meet with the condition like element is becoming enabled over a period of time. Otherwise visibility check is more than enough, clickable checking is at the third level which includes two of other checking within itself(element exist,element visible) which is completely not necessarily

Comment: @cnmuc Your current edit `How to check (ideally without using Javascript) if 4711 is clickable for a user, even if 4712 is not removed/hidden via Javascript.` changes the entire direction of the question. As per stack overflow standards you must not change the question once you have recieved well researched Answers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out. I am reverting the question for the this time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting for the invisibility of 4712 before checking the clickability of 4711. 4711 may still register as clickable while 4712 is still visible and that may be causing the issues.

```
new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(!ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.id("4712")));
new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("4711")));
```

Comment: I want to tell you, elementToBeClickable doesn't really check whether element is clickable or not, If it does it's job then the first line of yours is not necessary, the second line is more than enough. But it's a good workaround, that's what @cruisepandey suggested in the comment as well. So the answer is, we don't have the way to check whether element is clickable or not in selenium, we may do the workaround like you have done.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Indeed, this type of issue I had with automating an Angular1 Application. And this solution seemed to fit the bill. However if it is an Angular app, I would like to point out that ProtractorJS is far more proficient in getting around these types of issues since It by default will wait for angular elements to be enabled before interacting with them.

Comment: waiting for element to get enabled is not equivalent to waiting for element to be clickable, that's my whole my point, that's what Java Selenium Binding `elementToBeClickable` method is doing, but that's wrong. I code in WATIR which sits on the top of selenium and WATIR waits for element to become enabled before it triggers the click, but waiting for the element to become enabled is not equivalent to waiting for element to become clickable.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I'm not referring to the physical attribute of enabled that the IWebElement/WebElement returns but rather Angulars own interpretation of the page being fully rendered and all angular loading to be complete. See the docs https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular that is by default called before every click or sendkeys when using ProtractorJS. It's worth noting that ProtractorJS itself is specifically created to work to automate angular apps and is built ontop of Selenium. It's far more reliable then native selenium for angular apps.

Comment: So you are saying If page is completely loaded element is ready to be clicked? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @rajagopalan in situations like this where you are interacting and elements are changing browser.WaitForAngular is called be for each element interaction and it would handle all of these raise conditions, it worked flawlessly on all the times I had to implement workarounds like this example, they're completely unnecessary with protractorJS in all the angular products I've automated. It is well worth giving it a go for yourself and seeing if it solves all your issues you're envountering. The only downside is the need to switch to a different technology: JavaScript

Comment: I am using WATIR, I believe that there can't be another tool in this universe which can defeat it :(  No, you can't handle the above problem using your framework , you may find a workaround like you have given in your answer but no way to detect it. And also when an element is obscuring by other element you can't check whether element is clickable which is almost necessary here.

Comment: @rajagopalan newer things always come along. ProtractorJS was created by the angular team for angular applications, it is the supreme testing tool for automating angular apps, yes it handled all these issues I encountered. If you don't believe me maybe do a proof of concept using the tool :) I found it got around all of these problems for me. Maybe your app isn't angular? In which case I wouldn't know what tool is best for testing it, but for all angular applications, ProtractorJS comes out ontop for sure.

Comment: @rajagopalan no worries mate, I felt a bit frustrated when I found out all these c# methods I spent so long writing were already handled in ProtractorJS with its built in methods, but it's best to know now and use the right technology then spend more countless hours doing workarounds :)

Comment: Yeah same here as well, using selenium may be the right choice with legacy driver and also if website is pretty stable otherwise the one which sits on the top of selenium is necessary. I automate both very stable insurance application and highly unstable insurance application, for a stable one I can directly use selenium but for the highly unstable one I use WATIR, so I can imagine what would be your experience.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, a *Javascript* removes the element **4712** it is a bit unclear if the element *becomes stale* or *becomes invisible*. So for this step you can use either of the following options:

- [`stalenessOf()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.id("4712"))));
  ```
- [`invisibilityOfElementLocated()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("4712")));
  ```
- [`not`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-) along with [`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("4712"))));
  ```
- [`not`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-) along with [`presenceOfElementLocated()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("4712"))));
  ```

For the next step you want to validate if element **4711** is clickable or not and you can use the following line of code:

```
new WebDriverWait(browserInstance.getWebDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("4711")));
```

**Note**: An element's state as **`enabled=true`** and **`displayed=true`** isn't equivalent to element is **`interactable`** i.e. **`clickable`**