# Python-Selenium finds clickable element that cannot be clicked

Tags: python, selenium

I am using `python-selenium` to run automated tests. In the complex non-public environment these tests are running in I found something what I would label as a bug in selenium.

Basically what I try to do is to find some element in the DOM, when it becomes clickable, and then click it. The code is as follows:

```
....
what = (By.XPATH, '//button/span[contains(text(), "Load")]')
element = WebDriverWait(bspdriver.webdriver, 60).\
                until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(what))
element.click()
....
```

However, the `click` method fails almost immediately with the following error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="ivu-btn ivu-btn-primary ivu-btn-long ivu-btn-small" type="button"> is not clickable at point (1193.3332901000977,522) because another element <div class="ivu-modal-wrap vertical-center-modal circuit-loading-modal"> obscures it
```

I though I am waiting for the element to be ***clickable***! I assumed that `EC.element_to_be_clickable` means exactly that. But it does not. Is that a bug in selenium?

A workaround is the following code:

```
    mustend = time.time() + 60
    while time.time() < mustend:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(bspdriver.webdriver, 60).\
                until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(what)).click()
            break
        except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException,
                StaleElementReferenceException,
                ElementClickInterceptedException) as e:
            time.sleep(1.0)
```

which does not look so nice to me. Is there a way to improve the code? Is there a bug in selenium? If so, I can report it...

Used packages:

- selenium 3.8.0 and 3.11.0
- geckodriver 0.19.1
- python 2.7.12
- py.test 3.6.1

Full error message:

```
....
>       element.click()
selenium/test_pair_recording.py:66: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../venvs/linux_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
../venvs/linux_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:501: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
../venvs/linux_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:311: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fe69694fd90>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"element click intercepted","message":"Element <button class=\"ivu-btn ivu...gate@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:414:13\nclickElement@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:1220:5\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
        """
            Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

            :Args:
             - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
               object.

            :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
            """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                        value = value['value']
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if status is None:
                        status = value["status"]
                        message = value["value"]
                        if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get('message')
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
            exception_class = JavascriptException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
            exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
            exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
            exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
            exception_class = ScreenshotException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
            exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
            exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
            exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
            exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
            exception_class = UnknownMethodException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if value == '' or value is None:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
                raise exception_class(response, value)
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']

        screen = None
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']

        stacktrace = None
        if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                    line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                    file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                    if line:
                        file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                    meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                    if 'className' in frame:
                        meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="ivu-btn ivu-btn-primary ivu-btn-long ivu-btn-small" type="button"> is not clickable at point (1193.3332901000977,522) because another element <div class="ivu-modal-wrap vertical-center-modal circuit-loading-modal"> obscures it

../venvs/linux_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:237: ElementClickInterceptedException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it fails because `ElementToBeClickable` is waiting for element to be enabled, it's not really checking whether the element is clickable, it is assuming element is clickable if element is enabled, it's true actually but it fails here because element is enabled even when another element is overlay the desired element.

So write this code for the overlay to disappear

```
WebDriverWait(bspdriver.webdriver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ivu-modal-wrap vertical-center-modal circuit-loading-modal']")));
```

And then you write your code

```
what = (By.XPATH, '//button/span[contains(text(), "Load")]')
element = WebDriverWait(bspdriver.webdriver, 60).\
                until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(what))
element.click()
```

The above solution would work if the overlay is temporary, If it's permanant, then perform the Javascript click, because WebDriver internal check would stop you to do the click.

Comment: Thanks a lot that seem to have worked! But maybe I will file a bug report after all, as a 'click' means for me a 'click'...

Comment: @Alex Yes, exactly! Click means click!

Comment: @Alex I have written a nice answer as to why `ElementToBeClickable` method is not waiting for element to be clickable but for enabled so I gave a bigger argument as to why it's not waiting for element to be clickable but many people downvoted my answer, so I deleted it.

Comment: If I cannot click an element its not clickable. Simple logic. Selenium does it wrong!

Comment: @Alex Yes, exactly, I had a bigger argument with JeffC related to that, he continue to argue with me that it's still clickable and then I gave up!  Please read here the argument https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654804/elementtobeclickable-issues-with-selenium-java/51656361#51656361

Comment: Yes sure, Welcome!